# What is the correct way to run Rails tests without invoking the development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, environment

I have an Rails app, with some initializer code which must be executed when the app is running in development mode. However, this initializer code must not be executed when running tests.

I have established that

```
$ rake test
```

causes the app to be run in development mode, which invokes the initializer code and therefore breaks my tests. This is expected behaviour apparently (see: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9801).

What is the correct command to run my Rails app tests without starting the app in development mode?

Answer (score 1):

Does your test_helper.rb file look like the [default](https://gist.github.com/dimroc/1653316)? It should start with:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the rake task with an explicit environment:

```
rake test:units RAILS_ENV=test
```

If you don't specify an environment, development is assumed, in my experience. And while the test database still gets the fixture data inserted into it, stuff from the development environment still gets referenced for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a line at the start of the test_helper.rb file that says

```
Rails.env = "test"
```

You can't use

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
```

because it will fail to clear the cached value that returns from calls to Rails.env.